# Replace last instance of character (and there's more)

Tags: regular-expression, replace

I am trying to format a list that uses tabs for indentation so it will render as a [bulleted list on Confluence](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=lists). That means that each instance of a tab needs to be replaced with an asterisk (*), plus one leading asterisk, and then a space at the end of the string of asterisks.

Example:

```
Level 1
\tLevel 2
\tLevel 2
\t\tLevel 3
\tLevel 2
Level 1
```

Would become:

```
* Level 1
** Level 2
** Level 2
*** Level 3
** Level 2
* Level 1
```

I have tried doing a global replace (`s/\t/\*/g`) and then adding an asterisk at the beginning of each line, but that leaves me without the trailing space. I also tried the \ze atom as detailed [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6293/substitute-all-except-the-last-asterisk-in-groups-of-two-or-more-asterisks) (`s/\*\ze/\* /`), but that replaces the first asterisk, not the last. I feel like I'm really close but there's something I'm missing that will make this clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution I came up with:

```
:%s/^\(\t*\)/\="*" . substitute(submatch(1), '\t', '\*', 'g') . " "/
```

- `%s///`: Do a substitute on every line in the file
- `^\(\t*\)`: Match as many tabs as you can find at the beginning of the line
- `\=`: Allows us to use an expression in the replacement
- `substitute(submatch(1), '\t', '\*', 'g')`: Replace all the tabs with asterisks. (The `submatch(1)` selects the the first group of "memory parentheses" `\(\)`)
- `"*" . ... . " "`: Prepend an asterisk and append a space character

See `:h submatch` and `:h sub-replace-\=` for more info.

Comment: Shorter variation, just for fun: `:%s/^\t*/\='*'.tr(submatch(0), "\t", '*').' '/`

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the easiest way is to run 2 simple substitutions.

```
:%s/\t/*/g
:%s/\w/* &/
```

The first to replaces tab characters with stars and the second to puts an additional star and space before the first character.

If you can't use the `%` range then you can combine this with the global command, `:g`, to execute a command on each line that matches a pattern.

```
:g/^\t*/s/\t/*/g|s/\w/* &
```

We use the `|` to run 2 separate commands so we can run multiple commands in one line.

For more help see:

```
:h :s
:h s/\\&
:h /\w
:h :g
:h :|
```